# override form method from dll class

Tags: c#, overriding

i want to build dll file that deals with system.windows.forms.form how can i override any form method from dll class such as (WndProc)?

```
public partial class MyDll
{
    public MyDll(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
    {
        // i want to override WinProc form from my dll file.
    }
}
```

my project is a "ClassLibrary" not a "WindowsFormsApplication"

Comment: It is technically possible, very unwise however.  You can derive your own class from NativeWindow and call its AssignHandle method with the form's Handle.  Call ReleaseHandle() again when your WndProc() override gets WN_NCDESTROY.  Lots of ways to shoot your foot.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override the method in this way:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){...}
```

Here you can find some examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thank you so much just i want to know if i can override any form method from a dll file, my project is a "ClassLibrary" not a "WindowsFormsApplication"

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the form as a parameter you have the instance of the class, not the definition. You have to create your own Form, override the method as mentioned before and then pass this new Form to your MyDll constructor. for example:
Create a new class library project. Add two files:
- MyDllClass.cs
- MyForm (add new->Window Form)

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{    
     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    { 
        //your code here
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    } 
}
```

Then in MyDllClass.cs you will have

```
public MyDllClass(Form your_form_here)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: thank you so much just i want to know if i can override any form method from a dll file, my project is a "ClassLibrary" not a "WindowsFormsApplication"